# Properties of mbox message in mbox module in Python

Tags: python, email, mbox

I trying my luck to manage my mailbox with python.

My example code is

```
for eachmail in mailbox.mbox(mboxfile):
    print eachmail['From']
```

I got following by printing entire content.

```
Delivered-To
Subject
To
Content-Type
MIME-Version
Message-Id
```

Is there any full document showing what are all the properties I can get from the mbox message instance? Python docs doesn't specify any of these http://docs.python.org/library/mailbox.html#mailbox.mbox

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends entirely on what headers are in the message. Most of them are optional. Check [RFC 2076](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2076.txt) for common ones.

Answer (score 2):

Using your variables

```
mm=mailbox.mbox(mboxfile)
message=mm[0]
message.keys()
```

You can now access using mm['Subject'] or mm['Message-ID']

Answer (score 1):

Those are the email message headers. The specific headers will vary *drastically*, and you can't really count on *any* of them existing (even ones you would expect to exist like `To`, or `Subject`)… But Wikipedia has a pretty good list of common headers and their meanings: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email#Header_fields